# acceder a variables sin utilizar $_GET o $_POST

Tags: php

Buenas gente:

Bien a ver si soy capaz de explicarme. Estoy intentando desarrollar una app web multicliente. La app consta de dos directorios comunes, llamemoslos;

- app_admin.
- app_usuarios.

Y después para cada uno de los clientes tendrá su carpeta personal. La cuál tendrá enlaces simbólicos a los archivos comunes de app_usuarios, y cada carpeta de cliente tendrá un archivo "user.php" que guardará una variable $id_usuario=numero de usuario.

Bien mi problema viene cuando, accedo desde el login de app_usuarios se cargue la variable $id_usuario con el valor de ese cliente que accede. Hay alguna forma de realizar esta acción sin utilizar $_GET o $_POST.

Espero haber sido claro explicandome. Gracias.

Comment: Por qué no quieres utilizar `$_GET` o `$_POST`?

Comment: Yo te recomiendo usar [`sesiones`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.session.php). [Aquí un tutorial](https://codigosdeprogramacion.com/2016/12/20/sistema-de-usuarios-y-sesiones-en-php-y-mysql-1-login-sesiones-y-logout/)

Comment: @Flowen, si se pasa el `ID` del cliente por `GET/POST` el sistema sería muy fácil de `hackear`. Sería tan simple como hacer un par de intentos hasta acertar el `ID` de un usuario y acceder.

Comment: Suponiendo que no exista contraseña @Marcos

Comment: @Flowen, lo que yo entendí es que una vez 'autenticado', se usa el `ID` del cliente para acceder a los modulos. Es decir, que posterior al `login` el OP usa el `ID` y nada mas que eso para identificar el usuario.

Comment: No se entiende si quieres hacer un app multitenant o un app single-tenant donde usuarios distintos usan la misma aplicación. Por lo que dices sobre "carpeta personal" pareciera ser lo primero. Creo que necesitamos un esquema más detallado de la estructura de directorios. Además, todos los usuarios acceden al mismo dominio, o cada usuario tiene un subdominio? La url de login es común para todos?

Comment: y porque no usas _REQUEST ya que _REQUEST resibe $_GET y $_POST por igual

Answer (score -1):

Debes usar Session, si nunca la usaste debes tener en cuenta que session_start() debe estar ubicado al principio del archivo antes que cualquiel código HTML, ya que si no lo haces te va a dar error.

Elemplo de uso en la 1º línea del archivo

```
<?php session_start(); //Iniciamos o Continuamos la sesion ?>
```

---

complemento como se usa session, para cargar la variable por ejemplo la llamamos idioma y toma el valor de la variable $idio:

```
$_SESSION['idioma']  = $idio;
```

Luego para recuperar el valor en la siguiente página lo hace de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($_SESSION['idioma'])
{
    $idio   =   $_SESSION['idioma'] ;
}
```

esto se usa para proteger los datos a pasar de una página a otra

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta correcta, aunado a que el OP debe usar HTTPS para que sus credenciales y cookies no anden encueradas por el internet. Yo agregaría que de esta forma lo que viaja es una cookie que identifica la sesión y que si te la roban es posible fabricar requests con todo lo que sigue.